# ruby-debug-base19 :Failed to build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I ran the following command to install the gems

```
bundle install --without production
```

It started the installation untill it reached ruby-debug-base19 .When it tried to install it should the following error

```
Installing ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for insns.inc... yes
checking for insns_info.inc... yes
checking for eval_intern.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-cygwin -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_VM_CORE_H -DHAVE_ISEQ_H -DHAVE_INSNS_INC -DHAVE_INSNS_INFO_INC -DHAVE_EVAL_INTERN_H -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p429 -ggdb -O2 -pipe   -fno-strict-aliasing  -o breakpoint.o -c breakpoint.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-cygwin -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_VM_CORE_H -DHAVE_ISEQ_H -DHAVE_INSNS_INC -DHAVE_INSNS_INFO_INC -DHAVE_EVAL_INTERN_H -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p429 -ggdb -O2 -pipe   -fno-strict-aliasing  -o ruby_debug.o -c ruby_debug.c
ruby_debug.c:29:19: error: conflicting types for ‘rb_iseq_compile_with_option’
In file included from ruby_debug.c:4:0:
/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p429/vm_core.h:506:7: note: previous declaration of ‘rb_iseq_compile_with_option’ was here
Makefile:206: recipe for target `ruby_debug.o' failed
make: *** [ruby_debug.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ruby-debug-base19 -v '0.11.25'` succeeds before bundling.
```

What is the reason for this error and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`ruby-debug19`** is not maintained anymore.

But there's an alternative:

**[`debugger`](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger)**

Open your Gemfile

See if there's something like this...

```
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment it out, and use 'debugger' instead

```
#gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
gem 'debugger'
```

It is included in the rails Gemfile since 3.2.something to replace `ruby-debug19`. It has the exact same functionality and is actively maintained.